# How to automatically start services inside a docker container

Tags: linux, docker, restart

I am trying to find the best way to automatically start services inside a docker container once it has been restarted.

I don't mean starting the docker container on restart. I'm trying to achieve the following way:

1. I stop a container; and
2. when I start it again, the same services (processes) I was running before will start up again.

I.e. if I am running apache and ssh inside the container starting those service on container restart

Comment: You should have a look at supervisor https://docs.docker.com/articles/using_supervisord/

Comment: Or runit.  http://smarden.org/runit/

Answer (score 0):

That's really not the docker way (multiple processes per container). You can try to go down that path, as I did for several months, but you'll find that you'll be going against the docker team's design principles most of the time. I used the [phusion/baseimage](http://phusion.github.io/baseimage-docker/) base image and it really is well designed, with a good init process and support for run-it and ssh out of the box. Tread carefully, if you go down that path however.